# Can speak `be arbiters to their beauty`?

Tags: phrases

In my book I see:

> be arbiters of their beauty

but in my language sense, I think

> be arbiters to their beauty

is right too, am I right?
if is what's the difference between them?

Comment: What is the title of your book?  Please identify the source of your quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little sense to the usage of prepositions in English or any other language I have ever studied.

“Arbiters of X” means those who have the authority to make judgments about X, and so “arbiters” typically takes the preposition of attachment, namely “of.” In certain contexts, “arbiters in” or “arbiters for” are used to refer the arbiters involved in a specific dispute or with specific parties to a dispute, but “of” is the more common preposition used to delineate what general topic an arbitrator typically deals with.